# Confusion connecting iOS portion of Flutter App to Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, flutter

I'm attempting to connect the iOS portion of my Flutter app to Firebase. And as I go through the steps on Firebase - "**Add Firebase to your iOS app**" - I hit a step that says "*Add the initialization code below to your main AppDelegate class*" (Swift version):

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

  var window: UIWindow?

  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?)
    -> Bool {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
  }
}
```

But my AppDelegate class already has this code:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Not sure what to do. Do I replace the existing code with the code provided by Firebase or do I reconcile the two somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the given (predefined) `AppDelegate` class, there are 2 things you need to do additionally. 
They are

```
import Firebase  // <-- 1st add

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication,didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)

        FirebaseApp.configure() // <-- 2nd add

        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```

Comment: FirebaseApp.configure(), you can now safely remove it  FlutterFire automatically handles this for you. https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/#b-ios-installation

Answer (score 6):

Merge both code together:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
    override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
}
```